# Using Cucumber or RSpec+Selenium to create end user documentation?

Tags: ruby, documentation, rspec, cucumber, documentation-generation

Has anyone tried creating end user (potentially online, potentially to be printed) help/documentation out of your cucumber scenarios? Or taken screenshots for use in documentation using RSpec and Selenium RC's ability to do so?

For Cucumber, I'm imagining something like:

```
Scenario: If you want to add a link
Given I am on the edit blog post page
When I press the "add link" button
And I type in a link URL "http://stackoverflow.com"
And I click "OK"
Then the blog post should have 1 link
```

Translating to the documentation:

> If you want to add a link, go to the
>   edit blog post page. Press the "add
>   link" button and type a URL, like
>   "http://stackoverflow.com", into the
>   link URL field. Click "OK".

Would it be worth my time to try and, for one, write something to parse my Cucumber features into documentation, and two, to write/structure my Cucumber features in such a way as to create good documentation? Would the resulting documentation end up sounding really boring without much variation in the structure?

Is there anything else out there like this idea? [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) looks like it's more for code documentation than end-user documentation.

What about automatically taking screenshots? This seems like a more fruitful path-- just reuse the code that takes a screenshot when an RSpec test fails and have it take one in prescribed situations. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [cucumber-screenshot](http://github.com/mocoso/cucumber-screenshot) gem. It looks like it does exactly what you want--taking HTML or (if you're on a Mac) PNG screenshots of each step in your scenarios. (I was playing with [my own version of this idea](http://github.com/moss/visible-cukes) for a while last year. I dropped it pretty early on, so you're probably better off with cucumber-screenshot, but feel free to take anything you can use from Visible Cukes too).

Answer (score 3):

I use Lowdown (http://lowdownapp.com) to communicate features back and forth with clients. The whole point of cucumber is that it's business specific, so you shouldn't have to translate it to another format for documentation.  I kinda see where you're going, though.

You can use http://seleniumshots.com/ for getting screenshots from your app from the tests.  I don't know if it's out of beta yet, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds cool. Maybe you don't want some of the cucumber scenarios available to the whole world. If a developer put something sensitive, like people's names / development passwords; or a website exploit was discovered and a cucumber scenario was written to verify it was patched.